# How to replace multiple characters with a specific character in mysql with regexp_replace?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am using regexp_replace to replace a field of type string having some special characters with '_' where ever those characters are present.

I am using

`SELECT  regexp_replace('name', ' |\-|\(|\)|\.', '_') from db.table;`

```
Some values from the field 'name':

Pune Municipal Corp - Water
Kerala State Electricity Board Ltd. (KSEBL)
Paschim Gujarat Vij Company Limited (PGVCL)


What I want:

Pune_Municipal_Corp___Water
Kerala_State_Electricity_Board_Ltd___KSEBL_
Paschim_Gujarat_Vij_Company_Limited__PGVCL_
```

Comment: use for the regular replace in a function so that you have to write it only once

Comment: Were you able to get the issue resolved? If so, please mark the one that helped as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT  regexp_replace(name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75cfa8cce078806f6c8b83d05885d12d)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of mysql you're using but, on mysql 8+ you can use the native [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

Otherwise if the version which you're using don't support regexp replace, you could just create a function to do that.

Here is the function code:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Example using your regex and text:

```
mysql> select regex_replace('[ |\-|\(|\)|\.-]', '_', 'Pune Municipal Corp - Water Kerala State Electricity Board Ltd. (KSEBL) Paschim Gujarat Vij Company Limited (PGVCL)');
```

I got the code of the function [here](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `translate` to replace `space` and `-` with underscore(`_`) as follows:

```
Select translate(your_column, ' -', '__') from your_table
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=847653eb69f6e8a8114e12d2cadb5395)

Comment: Yes, this is for oracle.